# how can use multiple fields in for each part

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to edit multiple records at once. Is it possible update multiple fields in for each part?

```
Return db.tblname.where (z=> z.id == model.id).toList().foreach(z=> z.name =model.nam &&  z.active=model. Active)
```

It dose not accept &&.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't your for each do this?:

```
 .foreach(z=> {z.name =model.nam; z.active=model.Active; });
```